# Non-Orthodox converts and Olam Ha-Ba

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, reward-punishment, heterodox, olam-haba-world-to-come

Would a Gentile who converted through a non-orthodox movement be judged as a Gentile or a Jew in Olam Ha-Ba?

In regards to the judgement, would his/her action of converting and living a "Jewish" life which trangresses certain principles (i.e Reform Jews driving on Shabbat) be a grounds for punishment?

This is under the assumption that the Convert believes in G-d, attends services, recites daily prayers, and avoids treif meats and food combinations.

Answers from a vareity of viewpoints would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: "Answers from a vareity of viewpoints would be greatly appreciated!" according to non-orthodox movements, non-orthodox conversions are valid. according to orthodox judaism, they are not. such a convert could certainly fulfill the criterion of righteous gentile (a story: aime palliere, who was urged by r. elijah benamozegh not to convert and to instead become a noahide, served as a rabbi of a reform congregation in paris. when a congregant wanted to turn on a light, palliere would insist, "let me do that.")

Answer (score 9):

We can't possibly know how God judges people after they die. We know that he is compassionate, and I think it's safe to assume that he isn't going out of his way to punish people for things they didn't really understand. On the other hand, perhaps a person who believes himself to be Jewish but still violates halacha does receive punishment even though he was not really Jewish because he had intentions of violating halacha. Only Hashem knows the answers to these questions.

In general, in Judaism, we don't make our decisions according to what kind of reward or punishment we suspect we will receive in the afterlife as a result of those decisions. We make our decisions according to *halacha* and *derekh eretz* and we assume that if we follow those things, then reward will follow. The halacha according to most of the modern poskim is that someone who has a non-Orthodox conversion is not Jewish. This is especially true if the person never had in mind to keep all of the *mitzvot* after the conversion. Nevertheless, I am not able to tell you how God treats such people.

Comment: Citation of sources for the assertions in this answer, including the assertions of uncertainty, would make this answer more authoritative.