# Source that we don't know how God judges people

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, olam-haba-world-to-come

I wrote in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61242/1713), "We can't possibly know how God judges people after they die." I was making the point that the way we live our lives should be according to *halacha* but we can't possibly know what God does based on our *halacha* observance (e.g. I never spoke *lashon hara* even once in my life, so I know that I will get 35 *olam haba* points). This concept of uncertainty is something that I have taken for granted as long as I can remember, but in the comments, I am rightly [asked to source my claim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61227/non-orthodox-converts-and-olam-ha-ba#comment166550_61242).

I don't know the source of this claim, or even if such a source exists. I *think* the claim itself is true, but I have no evidence of this besides *svarah* (how *could* we know how God judges people after we die? Nobody has ever come back to tell us all of the details). I feel like I must have learned this at some point in my childhood, but perhaps it was just the *svarah* of whoever taught it to me. So is there a source for this idea in traditional Jewish thought?

Comment: לפום צערא אגרא ]15[

Comment: @DoubleAA That's very general. I'm looking for specifics.

Comment: Measuring the effort put in is practically impossible. Hence you can't determine how many points someone will get

Comment: @DoubleAA If we _could_ measure effort we still wouldn't be able to determine how many points we'd get. PA just says that reward is _proportional_ to effort, but it doesn't say what the coefficient of proportionality is.

Comment: @DoubleAA In any case, I think that's a pretty good _svara_. Do you know if there's a source for it?

Comment: Just set your unit of points to have a nice proportionality constant, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units. It's not like we have any grasp of what each point is worth anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA But then what have we learned? I don't care how many arbitrary-unit _olam haba_ points I have. I care about what _olam haba_ is actually like.

Comment: We (could have learned) the relative amounts of Olam Haba that I and Rabbi X got. But since we don't know the effort each of us put in, we no longer know.

Comment: @DoubleAA But again, I don't care about if I get exactly 0.37812 times as much _olam haba_ as Rabbi X. I want to know what _olam haba_ will be like for me.

Comment: ??? If you did know, as in your question, that not speaking Loshon Hara gets you 35 points, what would that mean to you? There's two issues here: we have no idea what olam haba is like, and, we don't know the relative value of various actions.

Comment: @DoubleAA The 35 points mentioned in my question were intended to be of some well-defined unit of utility.

Comment: I wrote up something about rational approaches to cheit, punishment and teshuvah at the end of my Aseres Yemei Teshuvah Reader (for people whose minds wander in shul) http://www.aishdas.org/10YemeiTeshuvah.pdf#page=44 see pages 42-47.

I think it's only tangentially related, so I'm commenting, not answering. It doesn't focus on after death in particular.

Comment: I see you've accepted an answer, but what do you think of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95327/hashem-as-the-judge-vs-his-omniscience

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mishna Torah Hilchos Teshuva 3:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=5&perek=3&halocha=2&hilite=):

> ושקול זה אינו לפי מנין הזכיות והעונות אלא לפי גודלם. יש זכות שהיא כנגד כמה עונות שנאמר יען נמצא בו דבר טוב. ויש עון שהוא כנגד כמה זכיות שנאמר וחוטא אחד יאבד טובה הרבה. ואין שוקלין אלא בדעתו של אל דעות והוא היודע היאך עורכין הזכיות כנגד העונות
>
> .. and this weighting [of merits vs. sins] isn't according to their number but according to their quality. There are merits that outweigh many sins ... and there are sins that outweigh many merits ... And this measurement is only in the knowledge of G-d and He is the one who knows how to evaluate merits against sins.

Commentaries ([e.g.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=12535&rid=405)) point to the Talmud, Kiddushin 39 as one of the sources for this statement.

Answer (score 5):

the mishna in avos says הוי זהיר במצוה קלה כבחמורא שאי אתה ידע מתן שכרן של מצוה, which i think means be careful with small mitzvos bec. we dont know what gd considers important

Answer (score 1):

The Maharal (intro to Gevuros Hashem) comments on how the Torah never says
where souls go after death. The Maharal's point was that the experience was
too foreign to our experience to be conveyed by prophecy. (His exploration
of the limits of intelligence and prophecy, and why intelligence can grasp
things that are beyond the range of prophecy is interesting, but tangential.)

The Maharal points out that the only thing the Torah does say is "so that
your days may be lengthened (idiom)". For while we can't understand what
existance after death is like, being told there will be such existence can
be understood.

The Rambam (Guide to the Perplexed III), and the Maharal (ibid) take this
verse to mean that the reward for doing mitzvos is to persist beyond death,
and the punishment is to cease to exist.

This view is a minority view.

The Talmud states in Tractate Brachos 28b: When R Yochanan b Zakai became
ill... there are two paths before me, one leading to Gan Eden and the other
to Gehennom [hell], and I do not know on which I will be taken, shouldn't I
weep?

We find similar mention of GE and Gehenom repeatedly in the Gemara.

The terms "Gan Eden" and "Gehenom", though, can't be taken overly
literally. GE in this context is not the place with the tree of knowledge
in Genesis 2 and 3. Similarly, Gei ben Hinnom is a valley outside of
Jerusalem (near the green line, in the middle of the modern city) where
children were sacrificed to Molech (a Pagan G-d).

Brachos 48b doesn't refer to two places in the afterlife, but only one --
much like the verse addressed by the Rambam and Maharal. "We found a source
for making a blessing on food, but where is [the source for] a blessing for
[learning] Torah? R Yishmael says: It is learnt by kal vachomer (a
fortiori). If a blessing is said for temporal life, for life in Olam Haba
(the world to come) how much more so!"

Or, Megillah 28b: Anyone who reviews halachah daily is guaranteed to be a
child of the world to come.

We even know "where" the WtC is, Koheles writes (12:7): The dust returns to
the dust that it was, but the soul returns to G-d who gave it. Or Job's
description (19:26): And after my skin is destroyed, without my flesh, I
will see G-d.

In order to resolve these two approaches we have to assume that either GE
and Gehenom are two different parts of the WtC, or they are two different
descriptions of the same place.

An idea I heard from R Aryeh Kaplan zt"l that caught my fancy is that the
two differ subjectively. (I believe it's also in the first volume of the RAK Reader.) To the good, the experience in WtC is pleasant, to
the evil, it is not so. Eden does literally mean "pleasant".

The Valley of Hinom was a place where flesh was mortified. Compare this to
Yeshaia's description of hell (66:24): They shall go and look upon the
corpses of the men who rebelled against Me; for their worm will not die,
nor will there fire be extinguished, and they shall be ashamed before all
flesh.

Yeshaia considered the fire of Gehenom to be shame. This is the conclusion
of R. Kaplan, as well as Ikarim 4:33 and Nishmas Chaim 1:13. The source of
shame is obvious, as the WtC is confronting G-d, with no hope of evasion.
Any sin still embraced stands clearly before you. "Whoever sins once
creates one accuser."

One last thought: we didn't discuss rebirth after the world to come, or the
general Jewish attitude that almost no one is eternally damned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the actual source, but there is a medrash that someone went up to shamayim (again, don't remember who) and saw that the elyonim were tachtonim and the tachtonim were elyonim.  I believe this is generally taken to mean that those who would be thought to be higher were lower while those who would be thought to be lower were actually higher, i.e. we do not know how Hashem judges us.  Sorry that I don't know the actual verse, but perhaps someone else can provide it?

Comment: You're probably thinking of https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0_%D7%90, but ואנן היכי התם כי היכי דאיתו אנן הכא הכי איתינן התם  ואנן - תלמידי חכמים היכי איתינן התם: